# Find the Fourier coefficients and Fourier series of the following function

Tags: fourier-series

Find the Fourier coefficients and Fourier series of the following function
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi e^{-x}}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}};\quad -\pi\le x\le\pi$$

**Here is my work:**

Since $L=\pi$ we obtain \begin{align*}a_0&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2\left(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}\right)}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-x}\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2\left(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}\right)}\Big[-e^{-x}\Big]_{-\pi}^{\pi}=\frac{1}{2} \\ a_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos\left(nx\right)\text{d}x=\frac{1}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-x}\cos(nx)\text{d}x \\ b_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\text{d}x=\frac{1}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-x}\sin(nx)\text{d}x\end{align*}

I'm stuck in $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$,  need help finding an easy way to solve this integration.

Comment: What's the problem? You're just integrating sines and cosines, as $e^{-\pi}$ is a constant.

Comment: sorry it's   e^(-x)

Comment: Okay - then it's just integration by parts. Also, as a user with 500+ rep, you should know how to use MathJax and not just paste things in an image.

Comment: i'm newbie in this system , sorry , I just need help

Comment: Integration by parts with a trick once you arrive at the same integral from integrating by parts twice

Comment: Notice that $$f(x)=\underbrace{\frac{\pi}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}}_{:=m}\cdot e^{-x}$$ and you don't need to carry $m$ in all of your calculations. Are you familiar with integration by parts? Do you know how to evaluate $\displaystyle \int e^{-x}\sin(nx)$?

Comment: i tried with parts but it's very long and didn't get result

Comment: Like I said, you need to use a special trick once you arrive at the same integral from integrating by parts twice...the trick is in adding the original integrals together and dividing by 2...

Comment: @user155971, I've edited your post. Please notice that you had a mistake in computation of $a_0$. Also, I find that Math Lover's hint is a bit easier than IBP. Up to you choosing what you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

IBP does the trick. Here's a start:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\int_{-\pi} ^\pi e^{-x} \cos{nx} \ dx = \frac{1}{n} \left(-e^{-x} \cos {nx}\Big|_{-\pi}^\pi - n\int_{-\pi} ^\pi e^{-x} \sin{nx} \ dx \right) $$

The first term is easy. Do another IBP on the second term and you'll get the original integrand, so do what you would do in calculus II and solve for the unknown integral afterwards.

Comment: I think you need to divide the integration,  from -pi to 0 and from 0 to pi

Comment: There's no need to - you'll get the same answer.

Comment: also there is mistake , it should be 1/n not in just n , in integration

Comment: Fixed - but of course, you can just add that in later as it's a constant multiplier.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, $$\left.-e^{-x}\cos(nx)\right\vert_{-\pi}^{\pi}=\cos(n\pi)\left(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}\right)=(-1)^n\left(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}\right)$$ i.e, the first term is not $0$.

Comment: Noted @Galc127, I must have thought of the sine one.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\int e^{-x + i a x} dx = \int{e^{-x} \cos(ax)dx + i \int e^{-x} \sin(ax) dx}.$$

Comment: Nice one ! (+1)

Comment: Thanks @Galc127. Using this method, we can get both integrals at the same time by computing the integral of an exponential.